# Standard way to include third-party node modules in an Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Didn't see any definitive instructions for this on the web. I'm looking for a familiar way to include those modules in my project. For example by including them in the app.module.ts file and then importing them in the relevant components.

Comment: Well, this is pretty much it. For example take a look at PrimeNG's DataTable: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable. You usually need to import the module to your app.module.ts, provide it and then import it in your components.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on the Place where the module is used. For Example if it is used in a particular module you can import that in respective module instead of doing that in app.module. This will eliminate the initial loading of the time and it will be much effective if you use lazy loading kind of things.

If that is used throughout the application  you can create a shared module where you can import and export these type of third party and common components, directives etc.